python 2.7.12 install on Ubuntu 22.04
I have an application running on Python 2.7.12 which was running on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the new Ubuntu 22.04 on a new system, but having issue with installing python 2.7 which I need to run my application. I am not a programmer, so I cannot adapt the Python code to be compatible with Python 3.x.

Python2.7 has been deprecated almost five years ago. You will either have to adopt the code to python3, or continue using an old/unsupported version of Ubuntu at your own risk.

How long is the code? What does the program do? We may be able to suggest an alternative if you share more information.

You mention "new Ubuntu 22.04 on a new system" which makes no sense to me; the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is the 2022-April release, so it's over two years old and not even the newest LTS release. If you're referring to 22.04.5 media; the release announcements said rather clearly "updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation" ie. its not a new product, just updated media (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/).  Looking for other solutions (updating code; containerization of code) would be safer

it is a SingApp 3.2.0 Application. I have no choice to write the code - the person who wrote it is no longer with the company. Unfortunately,

python2.7.18 should be available on Ubuntu 22.04 - but you will need to enable the universe repository

I updated apt universe/multiverse ... still the command apt install python2 (which is not installed) returns following: Package python2 has no installation candidate

I see python2 | 2.7.18-3        | jammy/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which shows its available for those listed architectures (you've not told us yours), so check your sources.  Did you sudo apt update to update your machine software lists after adding the universe repository; if not check your sources and any warnings/errors showing on apt update

python2.7 version 2.7.18 is available in the Ubuntu 22.04 default repositories. Ubuntu 22.04 is the last LTS version of Ubuntu that contains this package in its default repositories. The phrase "I installed the new Ubuntu 22.04" in your question worries me because the newest Ubuntu LTS is not Ubuntu 22.04; it's Ubuntu 24.04. Please run lsb_release -a to confirm what version of Ubuntu you are using.
The expected results of lsb_release -a are:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

To install python2.7 in Ubuntu 22.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python2.7  


Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7'

What version of Ubuntu are you using? python2.7 from the universe repository in Ubuntu 22.04 last got updated on  2024-03-14.
